# ath WiFi driver fails to load on a custom kernel

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, atheros

Recently I upgraded my `Ubuntu server` installation to 22.04. Since I use `aufs` and in Ubuntu it is turned off since 22.04, I had to build a custom kernel.
I followed the instruction from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) and everything went smooth, now aufs works.

**$ uname -a**

```
Linux redkin-server 5.15.0-86-generic #96+aufs SMP Thu Oct 12 15:57:09 MSK 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

BUT suddenly my WiFi adapter is no longer recognized!
I started to Google, and that is what I have found:

**$ sudo lshw -C network**

```
...
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fbff0000-fbffffff
```

**$ sudo dmesg | grep ath**

```
[   17.751102] ath: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_get_channel_khz
[   17.751124] ath: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_channel_khz (err -22)
[   17.751153] ath: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory
[   17.751162] ath: Unknown symbol wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory (err -22)
[   17.751191] ath: disagrees about version of symbol freq_reg_info
[   17.751200] ath: Unknown symbol freq_reg_info (err -22)
```

In such situations people say that some other driver is installed before `ath` module and advise to run `dkms status` and look for errors.
But the problem is, on my machine **sudo dkms status** shows nothing, empty output:

So, now I am lost and don't know where to go next. Help me, askubuntu mastermind, you are my only hope!

Here is the **lsmod** output: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/bvrPgQ8Byg/

Comment: Please run the terminal command: `lsmod` Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Done, see in the question

Comment: It appears that you built the *compat* suite that brings along it's own incompatible (!!) versions of cfg80211 and mac80211. Please explain.

Comment: I just followed the instruction: I left all the config options intact, only turned on AUFS, and then installed all the resulting .deb's.

Comment: Thanks, @chili555!!! Based on your advice, I've searched and found that the moduke compat.ko was installed by a deb file containing the package linux-modules-iwlwifi-5.19.0-41-generic. I've deleted this package, rebooted, and now my WiFi Works!
Thnaks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the precious hint given by @chili555 it was found, that my kernel has module named `compat.ko`, which installs some in*compat*ible version of `mac80211` driver:

**$ sudo lsmod | grep compat**

```
compat                 16384  2 mac80211,cfg80211
```

I've googled compat.ko and found that it is contained in a package called `linux-modules-iwlwifi`. If searched what is exact name of the package installed on my system:

**$  sudo apt list --installed | grep iwl**

```
linux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0-86-generic/now 5.15.0-86.96+aufs amd64 [installed,local]
```

after that I've removed this package:

**$ sudo dpkg -r linux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0-86-generic**

then I rebooted, and now my WiFi works!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working! You could also have done: `sudo apt purge linux-modules-iwlwifi*` *purge* also removes configuration files and all other cruft.